# How can I create a separate sbt Configuration or Task to compile with WartRemover?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac

[WartRemover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) is a scalac plugin. Typically it is configured via an [sbt plugin](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover/blob/master/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/wartremover/package.scala).

I'd like to be able to run WartRemover on my sbt project as a separate configuration or task without affecting the usual run of `compile`.

After adding Wartremover to my `plugins.sbt` I tried quite a few variations on the following.

```
lazy val Lint = config("lint").extend(Compile)

project("foo").
  configs(Lint)
  settings(inConfig(Lint)(Defaults.compileSettings): _*).
  settings(inConfig(Linting)(wartremover.wartremoverSettings):_*).
  settings(inConfig(Linting)(wartremover.wartremoverErrors := wartremover.Warts.all))
```

Afterward `scalacOptions` contained roughly what I expected inside my new `lint` configuration and in the `compile` configuration. However, when I ran `lint:compile` and `compile` with sbt in debug mode so I could see the command line arguments to scalac, either both or neither commands would result in pass the `-P:wartremover:...` switches. That was surprising because only `lint:scalacOptions` showed the `-P:wartremover:...` switches.

How can I create a separate sbt Configuration or Task to compile with WartRemover without affecting `compile:compile`?

Comment: Do you mean a custom command? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Extending/Commands.html#no-argument-commands

Comment: @gangstead, I'm not opposed to a custom command. I simply don't understand well enough how to make it execute 'compile' with the necessary configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you came really close. Here are some of the details:

1. sbt downloads library dependencies and compiler plugins all using `Compile` configuration's `update` task, which uses `libraryDependencies` setting. `addCompilerPlugin` is a shorthand for `libraryDependencies` with `CompilerPlugin` configuration.
2. Compiler plugin requires `scalaOptions` on the configuration that you're interested in.
3. You need to grab `sources` from `Compile` to use them in `Lint`.

If you see the implementation of [`wartremoverSettings`](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover/blob/v0.11/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/wartremover/package.scala) it's doing both `addCompilerPlugin` and `scalacOptions`. You have two options to disable wartremover on `Compile`:

1. Use auto plugin (requires sbt 0.13.5+) to inject `wartremoverSettings`, then manually remove wartremover compiler plugin from `Compile`.
2. Disable auto plugin, then manually add wart remover into `libraryDependencies`.

Here's the first option.

#### project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

#### project/wart.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.brianmckenna" % "sbt-wartremover" % "0.11")
```

#### build.sbt

```
lazy val Lint = config("lint") extend Compile

lazy val foo = project.
  configs(Lint).
  settings(inConfig(Lint) {
    Defaults.compileSettings ++ wartremover.wartremoverSettings ++
    Seq(
      sources in Lint := {
        val old = (sources in Lint).value
        old ++ (sources in Compile).value 
      },
      wartremover.wartremoverErrors := wartremover.Warts.all
    ) }: _*).
  settings(
    scalacOptions in Compile := (scalacOptions in Compile).value filterNot { _ contains "wartremover" }
  )
```

#### foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala

```
package foo

object Foo extends App {
  // Won't compile: Inferred type containing Any
  val any = List(1, true, "three")
  println("hi")
}
```

#### sample output

```
foo> clean
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 23, 2014 9:43:30 PM
foo> compile
[info] Updating {file:/quick-test/wart/}foo...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /quick-test/wart/foo/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 23, 2014 9:43:33 PM
foo> run
[info] Running foo.Foo 
hi
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 23, 2014 9:43:37 PM
foo> lint:compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /quick-test/wart/foo/target/scala-2.10/lint-classes...
[error] /quick-test/wart/foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:5: Inferred type containing Any
[error]   val any = List(1, true, "three")
[error]       ^
[error] /quick-test/wart/foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:5: Inferred type containing Any
[error]   val any = List(1, true, "three")
[error]             ^
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your suggested worked exactly as I'd hoped. I didn't seem to need to remove the AutoPlugin added configuration from Compile, which I'm guessing is because my build is specified in `.scala` files.

Comment: I was wrong: As Eugene said I needed the filter on scalac's options to remove the wartremover switch from being passed to in the Compile configuration. It wasn't noticing any effect from the switch being passed because by default the WartRemover plugin disables all warts. However, the WartRemover plugin was still being loaded by the compiler during `compile:compile` which isn't what I intended.

Comment: What does adding `Defaults.compileSettings` do? It causes some issues in our build; taking it out fixes them and seems to have no side-effects. (Our settings are all defined in lazy vals that are passed into projects's `settings` blocks, there's nothing on the 'top level' except `name`, `version` and `organization`.